# Why is "of" sometimes optional?

Tags: grammar

In the following two statements, I would say that "of" is required in 1 but optional in 2. I'm really asking "what is the difference between 'numbers' and 'couple' that makes this so?"

1: A number of people get lost in the park each year.
2: A couple of people get lost in the park each year.

2 could just as correctly (I might argue for "more correctly") be: "A couple people get lost in the park each year."

Is it due simply to "couple" being countable while "numbers" is not, or is there something else going on?

Comment: _A couple_ without _of_ is something I have heard in colloquial American English. It is certainly not grammatical in my English (I am from England). I have always believed it is a construction taken over from another language - probably either German or Yiddish - and not fully naturalied in English.

Comment: It surely isn't due to the fact that "couple" is countable, because many countable words require "of": a pair of, a trio of, etc.

Comment: Duplicate on ELU: [Why is "a couple of <things>" often shortened to "a couple <things>"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2407/191178)